# How can I pass parameters from the command line to $_POST in a PHP script?

Tags: post, command-line-interface, php, http-post-vars

I know this could sound a little weird, but I need to pass some parameters to the [$_POST](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) array. Similar to the way [Apache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_HTTP_Server) does it, or any other web server.

Unfortunately I couldn't find `libapache2-mod-php5` anywhere for my [Ubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29) installation.

Comment: see http://superuser.com/questions/149329/how-do-i-make-a-post-request-with-curl and it should be merged.

Comment: This is *not* about cURL. The canonical for that is ID 5647461, *"How do I send a POST request with PHP?"*.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That's not easily doable. You can invoke the `php-cgi` binary and pipe a fake POST request in. But you'll need to set up a whole lot of CGI environment variables:

```
echo 'var1=123&var2=abc' | REQUEST_METHOD=POST  SCRIPT_FILENAME=script.php REDIRECT_STATUS=CGI CONTENT_TYPE=application/www-form-urlencoded php-cgi
```

**Note**: Insufficient, doesn't work like that. But something like that...

---

It's certainly easier if you just patch the script, and let it load the $_POST array from a predefined environment variable.

```
$_POST = parse_url($_SERVER["_POST"]);
```

Then you can invoke it like `_POST=var=123 php script.php` for simplicity.

Comment: how is this better than just using cURL?

Comment: @Neal: The question wasn't about invoking a POST request to an URL, but directly on a script.

Answer (score 65):

Just insert the following lines at the beginning of your script:

```
/* If started from the command line, wrap parameters to $_POST and $_GET */
if (!isset($_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"])) {
  parse_str($argv[1], $_GET);
  parse_str($argv[1], $_POST);
}
```

This small piece of code does the trick (you may decide if you want to use [$_GET](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) or [$_POST](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) or, like I needed it, both.

After changing your script, you can call it from the command line passing your arguments:

```
php yourscript.php 'arg1=x&arg2=y'
```

Comment: This worked like a charm.  I'm actually using Zend's version of Eclipse.  I created a debug profile, as per Zend's documentation, and added PHP Script Arguments.  I put your code at the top of the PHP script and viola!  It parsed the arguments stored in $argv[] into the _POST array.  Much grats!!!

Comment: Didn't work quite like that for me (W10 OS): single quotes for the $_GET/$_POST arrays had to be replaced by double quotes.

Comment: Undefined index: REQUEST_METHOD

Comment: https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/passing-get-post-variables-to-php-via-command-line/5572/9

Comment: Does not seem to work properly with filter_input(INPUT_POST,...)

Comment: similarly doing something like this is awesome `parse_str(implode('&', array_slice($argv, 1)), $_POST);`, I found it on https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php#108883

Answer (score 1):

```
curl --data "name=ii" "param1=value1&param2=value2" http://test.com/sample.php
```

Comment: OP not asking for curl

Comment: I see no reason to downvote this. The OP didn't ask for curl, but he also wasn't very specific and this answer definitely works. It's also definitely easy. Upvoted.

Comment: Curl must go through the web server and he specifically stated that he wasn't using a server.