# Executing php script in perl with GET variables in url

Tags: php, perl

I have a perl script that executes a php script:

```
my $phpOutput = `/usr/bin/php /bart/bart.php`;
```

this works perfectly fine.  now i want to add some variables to the url.

```
my $phpOutput = `/usr/bin/php /bart/bart.php?data=1`;
```

this fails.

```
Could not open input file: /bart/bart.php?data=1
```

any ideas why?

Comment: I don't think it is really a URL in this context.

Comment: That looks like it is just executing it in the shell. Cant use http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php?

Comment: remove question mark and add `/` again and try?

Comment: @anantkumarsingh how's that going to resolve the issue?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17724485/2734189) has kind of an interesting way to handle this. But it looks like you will need to change the PHP script one way or another to be able to handle calling it this way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `?x=y` syntax is for web servers, whereas the CLI expects arguments separated by space after the filename. The way you've written it, PHP thinks that `?data=1` is part of the filename.

You could do

```
my $phpOutput = `/usr/bin/php /bart/bart.php 1`;
```

and use the `$argv` array to retrieve the argument `1` from within the PHP script. Since it's the first argument, it would be `$argv[1]` (the 0th index is the script name).

Comment: ok, thank you.  Now what if that "1" is a variable....my $phpOutput = `/usr/bin/php /bart/bart.php $someVar`;        would this work?

Comment: Sure, I see no reason it shouldn't.